# Formatting a string in Qt

Tags: qt, formatting, qstring

I'm using Qt 5.4.
I need to format a `QString` representing a number and make sure that it's always with 3 digits, adding trailing zeros.

Let me give an example:

- If the string is "1" I need "100".
- If the string is "13" I need "130".
- If the string is "472" no changes.

Is there a way to do this without checking the length of the string?

Comment: What the problem with the length? stringNumber += stringNumber.length == 1? "00": stringNumber.length == 2? '0' : ' ';

Comment: are you sure you want to get *from* "1" *to* "100" and **not** "1.00"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rellay don't want to use the lenght.... use the maths!

```
my_str = Qstring::number(my_str.toInt()*pow(10,2-log10(my_str.toInt())))
```

or:

```
my_str = my_str.append('0',2-log10(my_str.toInt()))
```

but it would be much simpler/quick to do this:

```
my_str = my_str.append('0',3-my_str.length())
```